# Change Wp_query args from blog to front page

Tags: php, wordpress, html, customization

So here is the code that makes a hero appear on the blog section of my wordpress site (when I populate a custom post type called "intro"):

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'intro', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

---more code here---

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm wondering what, if anything, I can change in the second two lines to make the effect happen on whatever page I choose as the home page.

Thanks

Edit 1:

```
<?php /* Template Name: eFrontpage */ ?>

<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'intro', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="point-1"></div>


<div class="home-intro" style="background-image: url(<?php   
the_field('background-image'); ?>)">

<div class="home-intro-inside">
  <h1 class="<?php the_field('intro_text_color'); ?>">
<?php the_field('intro-text'); ?>
</h1>
<a class="scroll-down <?php the_field('button_text_color'); ?>"   
style="background-color: <?php the_field('button-background-color');   
?>">
<?php  the_field('button-text'); ?>
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>

 <div class="space"></div>

 <script>


 jQuery("body").addClass("intro-is");


</script>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area container">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>




            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want, but if you want this code just for the front page, the you can place this code in front-page.php

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to change anything there. You'll need to copy the loop that creates the hero section into your front page template code. It may not work out of the box depending on the CSS that is styling the hero section.

You should also ensure you are using a child theme and not overwriting your original theme.

Comment: I created a new page template for the front page and added the code for the hero into the template but i'm getting the following error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in..."

Comment: Error saying what?

Comment: super newbie...shall I paste it here?

Comment: No, edit your question and place it at the bottom with an explanation.